# size of NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, size

Is there an equivalent to the MATLAB `size()` command in Numpy?

In MATLAB,

```matlab
>>> a = zeros(2,5)
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
>>> size(a)
 2 5
```

In Python,

```
>>> a = zeros((2,5))
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> ?????
```

Comment: Have a look at one of many such pages: http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Comment: I'm really curious why `shape` is an attribute of arrays and a function in the numpy model but **not** a method of array objects.  Is there an obvious answer?  Does it feel like it merits a separate SO question, or is it too potentially opinion-based?

Comment: Here is the updated [NumPy for Matlab Users](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) link.

Comment: @BenBolker  It's because it's setable. For example in this case, `a.shape = (10,)`

Comment: I ended up asking this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726674/why-is-shape-an-attribute-and-a-function-but-not-a-method-of-arrays

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This is called the "shape" in NumPy, and can be requested via the `.shape` attribute:

```
>>> a = zeros((2, 5))
>>> a.shape
(2, 5)
```

If you prefer a function, you could also use `numpy.shape(a)`.

Comment: We can switch freely between `np.method(x)` and `x.method` when x is a numpy object?

Comment: @Guimoute It depends.  First, `shape` isn't a method, it's a property.  And for many methods there are corresponding module-level functions, but not for all of them.  You need to consult the documentation for details.

Answer (score 14):

Yes numpy has a size function, and shape and size are not quite the same.

Input

```
import numpy as np
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
arrData = np.array(data)

print(data)
print(arrData.size)
print(arrData.shape)
```

Output

> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
>
> 8 # size
>
> (2, 4) # shape

Answer (score 2):

[w,k] = a.shape will give you access to individual sizes if you want to use it for loops like in matlab