# Why is shape an attribute and a function but not a method of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Experienced R user, relatively new Python user.

Will delete if the consensus is that this is too much of an opinion/mind-of-the-designer question.

I'm really curious why shape is an attribute of arrays and a function in the numpy module but not a method of array objects.   In other words,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array((1,2,3))
np.shape(a)   ## call function
## (3,)
a.shape       ## retrieve attribute
## (3,)
a.shape()     ## pretend that it's a method
## Traceback (most recent call last):
## File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
## TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

It's fairly obvious, *proximally*, why the last approach doesn't work (because `a.shape` returns `(3,)` and then we are trying to compute `(3,)()`), but I don't understand the design -- very naively, I would have expected a shape *method* to be the most Pythonic.

Comment: Why would it need to be a *method*? It doesn't need to be computed, it's not going to vary with arguments, it is a property of the specific array object.

Comment: But this *is* a primarily opinion-based question though; I'm not a core NumPy developer.

Comment: Why do you think a method would be more Pythonic?  The reason `np.shape` is a function is that you have to specify an argument (the array).  If you access it on a particular array, no argument needs to be passed.

Comment: Perhaps I'm too inexperienced and have been dealing with simpler types that don't even have attributes that the user wants to get at.

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) essentially recommends using an attribute whenever you can, a property if you need to do some functional computation but it's cheap so that it acts like an attribute, and a method only when you can't use either an attribute or a property (presuming the points maid by Martijn).

Comment: I don't think this is really a matter of opinion. It's a matter of _style_, certainly, but PEP8 pretty directly endorses this style, as @aruisdante points out.

Comment: You can also assign to the shape, i.e. `a.shape = (3, 1)` is (roughly) equivalent to `a = a.reshape(3, 1)`. You can't do that without having a `get_xxx` and a `set_xxx` method, and the namespace of numpy is already crammed enough.

Comment: An array has a number of other attributes (or properties): `a.stride`, `a.ndim`, `a.real`, `a.imag`, `a.base`, `a.flags`, `a.__array_interface__`, `a.T`, `a.dtype`, `a.nbytes`.

Comment: @Jaime to be clear, the reason that works is precisely because there is a getter and setter, they're just masked from the user by python's `@property` syntax so you never interact with them directly (I'm sure you know that, but the OP said new to python, so wanted to be explicit).

Comment: @aruisdante It is actually a little more involved, because `shape` maps directly to a data member of the object as defined in C. You can look at all the C-implemented getters and setters for `ndarray` [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.9.x/numpy/core/src/multiarray/getset.c#L904)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As aruisdante notes, [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#designing-for-inheritance) says:

> For simple public data attributes, it is best to expose just the attribute name, without complicated accessor/mutator methods.

I think the actual convention in practice is even a bit more than that.  If what you're getting from the object is just static data, there is no need to make it a method; it can just be an attribute.  That is, if an object has data attached to it that is already calculated and stored, it can be stored as an attribute.  Methods are more commonly used when retrieving the needed data requires some sort of actual computation to be done every time you retrieve it.  (Properties allow for "transparent" computation even on simple attribute access, so that `obj.attr` actually runs a function to calculate the result, but using this for any heavy computation would be considered a bit sneaky.)  Also, of course, if you need to pass arguments in order to get the data you want, it has to be a function/method (which is why `np.shape` is a function).  There is certainly scope for differences of opinion here, and there are indeed libraries that vary in what they expose as attributes vs. methods.

So, since `shape` is a simple fixed feature of the array, it doesn't need to be a method.

Comment: The other advantage to starting with an attribute-first mentality is that you can always convert an attribute to a property without breaking any dependent code, but once you decide to make something a method it has to stay that way for life unless you want to cause your users a lot of pain.

Comment: Is this a feature of Python? Because having accessor methods (i.e. getters) with no additional computation is pretty normal for other OOP languages like C++ and Java.