# NumPy equivalent of MATLAB size()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, size

Is there an equivalent to the MATLAB `size()` command in NumPy? I have found one other question ([size of NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125429/size-of-numpy-array)) similar to this, but our questions are not the same. They had an array, so the `size()` and `shape()` functions should work fine.

In my case, I have a vector in some cases and an array in others. I want to use something like:

```
a = [ 20, 30, 40, 45, 50, 60] # angles
alpha = np.array(a) 
[mm,nn] = size(alpha)
```

I want it to return `[mm, nn] = (6,1)`, but `alpha.shape` returns `(6,)`. This poses a problem since the next part of the code is a for loop:

```py
for i in range(nn):
    print (i) #do stuff
    for ii in range(mm):
        print (ii) #do stuff
```

In this case I have a vector so `len(alpha)` would work fine, but sometimes alpha is an array. I suppose I could use:

```py
mm = alpha.size
nn = alpha.size/len(alpha)
```

But, I'd imagine there would be a better way. Is there a command like `[mm,nn] = size(alpha)` in MATLAB?

Comment: In numpy, arrays are "ndarrays", i.e."N-dimensional arrays". I don't know MATLAB, but if `size()` in MATLAB returns 2 values, the arrays it works on must be 2D...

Comment: @richardec that's my point...I want it to be able to handle a vector or an array.

Comment: IIUC `mm, nn, *_ = alpha.shape + (1,)`.

Comment: @AlexCushley "In my case, I have a vector in some cases and an array in others." No, *you are only working with arrays*, "vector" doesn't refer to anything in particular as distinct from a `numpy.ndarray`. You array has the shape `(6,)`, it is unclear exactly the semantics you expect for your array to give a shape that it doesn't have. Probably, a better solution is just to make sure your arrays always have two dimensions if that is what you were expecting

Comment: This seems like an XY problem to me, the *actual* problem is your for-loop. Why are you trying to loop like that over your array? What do you *actually* need to accomplish?

Answer (score 4):

`.shape()` returns a tuple. Since we can check the length of tuples, we can just define a custom `size()` function that inserts a `1` if the array is 1D:

```py
def size(arr):
    if len(arr.shape) == 1:
        return arr.shape[0], 1
    return arr.shape
```

Answer (score 0):

`shape` IS the `numpy` equivalent.

```
In [127]: alpha = np.array([20, 30, 40, 45, 50, 60])
In [128]: alpha.shape
Out[128]: (6,)
```

MATLAB matrices are always 2d (or higher), so `size` will have 2 values.  But `numpy` arrays can be 1d, or even 0d.  So shape may just have 1 value as in (6,).

Sure you could construct `mm,nn` with these values:

```
In [129]: mm, nn = 6, 1
```

and even iterate on the ranges, but that doesn't help you access the elements of `alpha`:

```
In [130]: for i in range(nn):
     ...:     print(i, alpha[i])
     ...:     for ii in range(mm):
     ...:         print(ii)
     ...:         print(alpha[i, ii])
0 20
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [130] in <module>
    print(alpha[i, ii])
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

`alpha[0]` is `20`, but `alpha[0,0]` raises this error.  `alpha` is **1d**.

There are various ways of making a 2d array:

```
In [132]: beta = np.atleast_2d(alpha)
In [133]: beta
Out[133]: array([[20, 30, 40, 45, 50, 60]])
In [134]: beta.shape
Out[134]: (1, 6)
In [135]: beta[0, 3]
Out[135]: 45
```

or adding a trailing dimension:

```
In [136]: alpha[:, None].shape
Out[136]: (6, 1)
```

Sometimes we call these arrays "row vector" or "column vector", but in either case they are 2d arrays;

```
In [137]: beta
Out[137]: array([[20, 30, 40, 45, 50, 60]])
In [138]: alpha[:, None]
Out[138]: 
array([[20],
       [30],
       [40],
       [45],
       [50],
       [60]])
```

Sooner of later you need to become comfortable with the multiple-dimensions of `numpy`.  Trying stick with the MATLAB notions will, in the long run, be frustrating. There are some older helps for way-ward MATLAB users, such as the `np.matrix` class, and https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

In python it is possible to iterate on lists and arrays directly, and use `enumerate` if you also want an index:

```
In [140]: for i, v in enumerate(alpha):
     ...:     print(i, v, alpha[i])
0 20 20
1 30 30
2 40 40
3 45 45
4 50 50
5 60 60
```

But `numpy` we prefer not to iterate - not even with one level.  And often we don't need to. (Same is/was true in MATLAB.  Whole matrix opertions are preferable, though its jit compiling reduces the time penalty of iteration.)

```
In [141]: np.arange(alpha.shape[0])
Out[141]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
In [142]: alpha
Out[142]: array([20, 30, 40, 45, 50, 60])
In [143]: alpha * np.arange(alpha.shape[0])
Out[143]: array([  0,  30,  80, 135, 200, 300])
```